# Windows.Security.Credentials does not resolve

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security, credentials

I tried to implement a Credential Vault based on the Windows.Security.Credentials Class, but Visual Studio claimed it did not no of any such thing. I could not find the Windows.Security Assembly, so i created a new UWP Project, which instantly could resolve the reference.
My Problem now is, that while the UWP Project resolved it just fine, the class library that i want to pass around to multiple projects still can't and I still can't find the assembly (or wherever else this namespace might be).

can you please help me in finding out what i have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Windows.Security.Credentials` is only available in UWP